# Test Failing Because of Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have written a test in Jasmine to show an alert when any kind of error for a certain service exists. The code in question lives within the component and is essentially an else to show an alert.

I have tried multiple methods, ranging from providing a request with a 'GET' and supplying the URI for the api path - then using a flush on it. I have checked it with and without whenStable(), yet no luck.

```
it('should show alert when an error for service exists', () => {
  spyOn(alertService, 'showAlert').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(someService, 'getStuff').and.returnValue(new Error());
  const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#search'));
  input.nativeElement.value = 'something';
  input.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(alertService.showAlert).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm expecting for the alert to show when there's an error. This test passes, however if I add a '.not.toHaveBeenCalled()' instead, the test will pass as well. Stack trace doesn't throw an error, but shows 'ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', ' : Expected a spy, but got Function.'.

Do you see anything that stands out which I should correct in the previous logic?

Just to clarify, the code in question is in the ngOnInit within the component and is the exception to receiving 'stuff' from the service.

Comment: Use `async(() => { ... })` instead if just `() => { ... }` as the second argument to it(). Ore return the promise: `return fixture.whenStable()...`.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Do you mean that the test still passes whatever you expect in the promise callback? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: That's right - the test passes no matter what in the promise callback. If I expect the showAlert to be called, it passes. If I expect for showAlert to not be called, it passes.

Comment: Without a complete example allowing to reproduce the issue, I can't help more, sorry.

Comment: Right, I understand. This was all in response to a simple showAlert error, but I was just looking to see if there was any flaw in my understanding of how I set up the test. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Can you please share your TestBed configuration for the test?  this might help diagnose the issue better.